# Stop VS from putting a property value in the .Designer.cs file

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, properties, user-controls

I have a custom control which I have dropped onto a form in Visual Studio 2010 and c# winforms.

When I drop the control on the form the properties are automatically populated in the From1.Designer.cs file.  I want to stop a specific property from appearing in the file.  I have already marked it as `[Browsable(false)]` but this is not enough to stop VS from interfering with my property.  Is there an attribute to the VS to ignore the property?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this if you want that property to be serialized:

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
```

Instead if you want to stop the property to be serialized if it has its default value you can do what @HandPassant pointed out in the comment and apply the `DefaultValueAttribute` (it'll be serialized only if the value is different from the default you specified).

Comment: Yup, [DefaultValue] is also a strong contender.

Comment: @Adriano very true.  I can not have a default value because the property is only valid once the system is running and security access to a database has been granted.  In this senerio I wanted VS to leave the property value alone.  PS - There was a bit of delay in accepting the answer because I had to wait 15 minutes and only had ten minutes left before I had to go and get my train home!